# how do i position a js dialog box with a translucent background in the middle of the viewable area of the page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

as the page gets longer due to the increase in the table items, if i click on button to open the dialog box it shows up at the top of the page and i have to scroll back to top to view it. i want it to appear in the middle of the view port wherever i am on the page.

i am making an ajax request to a php page in order to build up the html markup and then append the responseText to a div element.

the css code for the background as well as the dialog box that will overlay it is as:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 div.Background {
background: #FFF;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
filter:alpha(opacity=28); 
-moz-opacity: 0.8; 
opacity: 0.8;
z-index:999;
 }
   div.Box {
border:1px solid #bbb;  
background:white;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:-280px;
margin-top:-195px;
width:500px;
height:420px;
z-index:1000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #ccc;
 }

 </script>
```

Also please note that i have changed the backgrounds position to relative keeping the box's position absolute to no avail and that i dnt want to use any jquery or similar stuff. so please i request not to suggest those solutions. Just so u guys know.. 
Please reply, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you have your CSS rules within a script tag, which is incorrect.  They should be within a style tag, ie:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*CSS rules here */
</style>
```

Now for your question: instead of giving the element `position:absolute`, change that to `position:fixed`.  This allows you to position you box **relative to the window** and it will stay in the same position even when you scroll the rest of the page up and down.  See a simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGmyM/1/).

One thing to note is that IE6 doesn't recognise `position:fixed`, but you may well not care about that.